# Trying to add FaceBook comment plugin in my webPage, why the data-href property is not setting in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my Jquery Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#commentsec').data('data-href','http://googlennn.com');

    });
</script>
```

Here is the Div where i want to set:

```
<div id="commentsec" class="fb-comments" data-href="" numposts="5" data-width=""></div>
```

Comment: `.data('data-href'` should be `.data('href'`.  It won't update the HTML as `.data(value)` calls are stored internally to jquery.  Use `.attr("data-href", val)` to update the HTML.  See the duplicate for a lot more details.

Comment: No i have already used this .attr("data-href", val) but still not working.

Comment: Why didn't you add that information to the question?

Comment: sure i will update this.

Comment: No worries - here's a fiddle showing that `.attr("data-href")` works fine (jsfiddle have added a console that you might need to expand at the bottom of the output window) https://jsfiddle.net/nws7hj8f/

Comment: The question is: how are you testing that it's not being set?  Changing the attr won't change the data if it's already been read as it's cached and changing the data won't change the attr because that's not how it works.

Comment: Just a small Mistake i have done..The Jquery version  which is refered has removed.That is why it was not working.After adding proper jquery its working nnow.